# Compare datasets in sql query with pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Cannot see online and therefore not sure if this is possible? Can I make a query to sql that will compare columns in sql to existing pandas dataframe ?

EDIT: adding more of sample code

```
df_local = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
result = pd.read_sql(
f""" 
SELECT * FROM sql_dataset 
  WHERE sql_dataset.col1 =df.col1 
  AND
  sql_dataset.col2 =df.col2
""" )
```

Comment: yes you can friendorinol, but for that you will need to convert your read_sql statement to a pandas df

Comment: This would need a little more detail, but you absolutely can do this. If you provide some sample code we can probably help get you a more exact answer

Comment: Oh, this is nice to hear. I have added a little more of the sample code. Basically I just have data frame and sql table in the server and since the table is too big to pull completely, I just want to get all rows where two columns in sql table match two columns in my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_local = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
col1_list = df_local['col1'].values.tolist()
q_col1 = ', '.join([str(row) for row in col1_list])

col2_list = df_local['col2'].values.tolist()
q_col2 = ', '.join([str(row) for row in col2_list])

concat_list = ["'"+str(c1) + ' ' + str(c2)+"'" for c1, c2 in zip(col1_list, col2_list)]
q_concat = ', '.join([str(row) for row in concat_list])


q = "SELECT * FROM sql_dataset WHERE CONCAT(sql_dataset.col1, ' ', sql_dataset.col2) in (" + q_concat + ")"

result = pd.read_sql(q)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I am looking for. I would want to compare values from rows between columns in sql dataset and pandas data frame. Your answer would check for column names I belive

Comment: Oh ok sorry I think that I understand now, I've edited the answer do not hesitate telling me if it's better

Comment: thanks again, this would partially work but in my example this would match rows `1,3`, `1,4`, `2,3` and `2,4`. In my case I am looking to match only rows `1,3` and `2,4`

Comment: Ok so I've edited again. I've tried to concatenate col1 and col2 to get an 'ID' that you can use to retrieve data. 
The printed query from python looks like this : "SELECT * FROM sql_dataset WHERE CONCAT(sql_dataset.col1, ' ', sql_dataset.col2) in ('1 3', '2 4')"

Comment: oh, nice! that does it, I didn't know abut sql `concat`